# Sending large volume of data between two C# programs

Tags: c#, ipc

I am currently working on a C# (I could use python also) plug-in for two separate programs that need to communicate. In the first first program, I deconstruct 3D geometry into edges, points, normals, etc. Then I send all of this data to my plug-in in my second program to be rebuilt. Ideally this would happen as fast as possible to keep things i "real time".

Currently, I am converting my data with JSON, and writing the JSON to the disk. Then my second program watches for file changes, and then reads the file and uses the JSON data.

By far the biggest bottle neck of my entire plugin is the read/write process. There has to be a faster way than writing to a file.

Comment: MemoryMappedFiles: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx. You'll have to do a bit of sharing at the start using files, but after that it'll all be done on RAM.

Comment: Use a named pipe. Check out `NamedPipeServerStream` and `NamedPipeClientStream`

Comment: A MemoryMappedFile will introduce as much  problems as it solves.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Explain...

Comment: I'd probably use WCF and start with a NamedPipe binding.  At least it would be relatively simple to switch to TCP binding if you needed to share the data across multiple machines.

Comment: What is the size of the data? KB? MB? GB?

Comment: @HenkHolterman MMF is free of problems once you know what you are doing. Named pipes in the opposite are source of hard to track bugs and complexities.

Comment: Memory-mapped files. With proper design you can avoid copying and serializing data *at all*.

Comment: Right now the size is in the MB range. I would also be interested in memory mapping but it is hard to find a simple setup that I could replicate. I am unsure about the "proper design"

Comment: Eugene, do you have any links that might talk about the proper design of Memory Mapped files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to use interprocess communication.
The most well known are used between different machines: WCF(.NET 3.5) and Remoting(.NET 2)

For on-machine communication you can choose to use Named pipes or Memory mapped files.

Memory mapped files are similar to your solution in that they use the page file as a backup.

I think the Named pipes solution is the most convenient:
You set up a "server" stream and wait for some "client" to connect.
Then you transfer the data just as you would through any other stream.

[Here's NamedPipeServerStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream.aspx).
[And this is NamedPipeClientStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream.aspx).
The code example there pretty much covers it.

Comment: Thanks! I had read a little bit about memory mapped files, but I was not sure if that was the way to go. I think I will give named pipes a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think WCF with named pipes would do the job, you just have to create transfer objects, which will be serialized and it will be all done by WCF automagically, or you can just prepare your existing objects to be transfered by named pipe with not really big overhead. Using json would be nice but it creates additional layer, and with WCF you transfer objects which can be used right away without translation by json. (Really they are translated to xml but you are not doing it by yourself so it is better then you could do with parsing json I think).